# How to clear a single layer among a group of layers in jCanvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, jcanvas

I am using the latest version of jCanvas. I have two layers on my canvas. I have a function which draws those 2 layers. Everytime the function is called, I want to clear one layer and keep the other layer intact cause I'm plotting a curve on the latter. How do I clear a single layer using jCanvas? I could not find anything on clearing layers in the documentation of jCanvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you use the **removeLayer()** API.  Here's the [API doc](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/layers/#removing-layers)<strike>, make sure you heed the part about calling drawLayers() after calling removeLayer()</strike>.

UPDATE 2013-02-16:  Since jCanvas version [13.02.11](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/commit/39fec4bf3ea68e602f2141b2ba511183e29d4412), **drawLayers()** happens automatically after the user calls **removeLayer()**, so the explicit drawLayers() call by the user is no longer necessary.  Also since the 2013-02-13 commits, there is unit test code in the "[tests](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/tree/master/tests)" subdirectory that demonstrates the new functionality.

Comment: thanks for the link. But if I remove the layer and then again redraw it, will it be cleared ? or  will it have the same content drawn on it before i removed it?

Comment: @Mohit, since you originally asked this question, the jCanvas behavior has changed.  Please read my 2013-02-16 update in the accepted answer.